# Tracking multiple webservices in Loadrunner

Tags: web-services, loadrunner

I am new to loadrunner and have read some tutorials. My application is invoked via a SOAP web service call from soap UI and I get a synchronous response immediately. Then my application starts processing request and makes many web service calls internally and some business logic processing as well. Based on the result of the web service calls, a table in my application is populated in GUI with the web services and their results. But everything happens internally. I have to keep refreshing the page to get the latest update in the table till all the services are completed. 
How do I track such web services which are invoked internally from my application? In tutorials, I could see recording from browser. But this is different. The browser itself doesn't send any requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use proxy recording and set your application to use the LoadRunner recording proxy for web.   Don't forget to add the SOAP header afterward